# test if column exist and copy it and drop it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to copy column values of table1 to table2 and drop it after that from table1 like this

```
IF COL_LENGTH('table1', 'coltocopy') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table2 (coltoreceive)
    select coltocopy from table1
    ALTER TABLE table1
    DROP COLUMN coltocopy
END
ELSE
print 'no action'
```

the first time it's ok but if a run this script another times, i have error like

```
Invalid column name 'coltocopy'.
```

the IF COL_LENGTH('table1', 'coltocopy') IS NOT NULL don't work ?
same result with *IF EXISTS* command

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? SQL (the standard query language) has no `IF` or `ELSE` statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails on the second try because you dropped `coltocopy` on the first try, which means `SELECT coltocopy FROM table1` is no longer a valid statement. It doesn't matter that you know the script won't actually hit that point if `coltocopy` doesn't exist, the engine will still check the whole script and error on it. I believe you need dynamic sql to avoid that error.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max) = 'INSERT INTO table2 (coltoreceive)
                             select coltocopy from table1
                             ALTER TABLE table1
                             DROP COLUMN coltocopy'

IF COL_LENGTH('table1', 'coltocopy') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    EXEC (@SQL)
END
ELSE
PRINT 'no action'
```